# How to force imagemagick to keep the original colorspace of an image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a problem using imagemagicks convert and keeping the colorspace.

I have a JPEG that is just black (this is an edge case). When I run identify on it this is the output:

`black.jpg JPEG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 12787B 0.000u 0:00.000`

I then add some text to the image:

`convert black.jpg -pointsize 50 -fill WHITE -draw "text 100,100 'foobar'" test.jpg`

Now running identify on the resulting test image shows:

`test.jpg JPEG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 11316B 0.000u 0:00.000`

I tried to add the `-colorspace sRGB` option but it did not help at all. No matter what I do, the colorspace is always converted from sRGB to Gray.

How can I tell imagemagick to leave the colorspace as it is in the original image?

> ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 arm 20190101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Imagemagick, for most formats you can just add -type truecolor. For example:

```
convert black.jpg -pointsize 50 -fill WHITE -draw "text 100,100 'foobar'" -type truecolor test.jpg
```

should do what you want.

Note for PNG you need to add PNG24: to preface the output as PNG24:test.png

Comment: Did not work for me (I want my output to be RGB not sRGB)

Comment: If you really want linear RGB (would be darker), then add -colorspace RGB to the command. Can you post an image example?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your problem is caused by a bug in ImageMagick, with the fix https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/commit/59953e741c004f84b4a164d430a1be5ca3db2d44

Comment: I edited to make more obvious that you are answering to the question at the top of the page. Let me know if I am mistaken in that assumption.